# DNN search not working - macedonian

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

Standard search module not working with 'cyrilic' search on DNN 7.4. I have another web site with 'cyrilic' content but on DNN 7.3 version - there is no problem and works very well .. On both sites i have English content ,and search works well. So my problem is only ot 7.4 only when search 'cyrilic'. I was try everything : folder permission , re-index content .. Someone help ?

Something that i find today .. 
In SearchResults module , in SearchResults.ascx file , in SearchTerm variable i have encoded query string when debug it. I was search for something like : ТЕСТ on cyrilic and i have this value : ÑÐµÑÑ ..
this is not decoded query string .. so thats my problem , but how to fix it ?
And in URL i have : /Search-Results/Search/тест .. it`s not ok , it must be 
/Search-Results?Search=тест

Why this happens ? Anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , i found some kind of "solution" ..
I tried so many things but the problem with encode/decode still exist , so i made changes to SearchResult module in SearchTerm field.
Replace : HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["Search"])
with Request.RawUrl , just remove DNS and in final get querystring as plain text .. It`s a very wrong way to deal with the situation , but i was totally exhausted to search a solution.